# Meteor & Mongo: addToSet inserting

Tags: meteor

I have some documents in my base:

```
//example docs
{"_id": "qwerty12345", "name": "Bob", "cards":["cardId1", "cardId2", "cardId3"]}
```

I'm using this for inserting data:

```
Template.insert.events({
    'click add': function(){
        if(confirm("Add card?"));
        mycollection.update({_id: Session.get('fooId')}, { $addToSet: { cards: this._id}})

    }
});
```

Then i'm using this helper for my template:

```
Template.index.helpers({
  cards: function(){
        query = mycollection.findOne({_id: Session.get('fooId')});
        return query.cards;
    }
});
```

And in template:

```
<img src="{{img}}" class="add">
{{#each cards}}
{{this}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

This works perfecty, but i have a trouble:

As you see, every image have id and url({{image}}), i'm need to add image url to 'mycollection' too for every card(on click).

How to make it?

And the second problem:
How to allow mongo insert duplicates to "cards" array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean every card has id and image field? I guess so.

You can add nested object to an array fields. Like that

`mycollection.update({_id: Session.get('fooId')}, { $addToSet: { cards: {id: this._id, image: this.image}}})`.

In the template:

`{{#each cards}}
{{this.id}}: {{this.image}}<br>
{{/each}}`

For second problem: You can use `$push` instead of `$addToSet`